# What is the most effective way to get a list down into a sproc from an application?

Tags: sql

There are a few alternatives I am aware of:

- Delimited literal (e.g.  'Item1,Item2'  or 'Item1:Item2')

  - Requires splitting and processing, which isn't natively supported
- XML fragment (e.g. )

  - incurs overhead with XML processing, which I am assured is pretty hefty

Another one I thought of was to actually write away list items before requiring them in the proc (tighter than tight coupling here) with a batch insert of some sort.

And yet another way would be to apply the logic required of the list items in the biz layer on data retrieved.

Im aware that it may just be a case by case call, but would like to know, as a rule, what is the preffered way. I hate ambiguity, but should embrace it, now there's a dichotomy.

Comment: Which SQL is this - Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer...?

Comment: MSSQL. I thought that the db tech would be almost neglible (with the view that implementations for the problem would recruit similar mechanisms)

Comment: similar topic at: parameter-passing-vs-table-valued-parameters-vs-xml-to-sql-2008-from-net-applic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MSSQL 2008+ the best way is table typed parameters, for versions prior to 2008 there are bunch of weird decisions - starting from Xml or comma-separated strings and ending with persistent table with call sessioning and cleanups.

Answer (score 1):

From the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014571/since-there-is-no-sqlserver-array-parameter-whats-the-best-way-to-proceed), there is an extensive discussion of the topic [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html).